# CSS and D3 - Making Responsive SVGs in FIREFOX

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, d3.js

I am using D3.js.
I have successfully gotten it to append a SVG element on a element and start doing SVG drawings on the main SVG.

I would like the SVG element to be responsive, so I decided to set attributes width and height to both 100%.

I then created a div:

```
<div id='divForCharts' class='divCharts'>

</div>
```

Then made that div a RESPONSIVE SQUARE through CSS:

```
.divCharts{
  width: 50%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;


  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

As in the css above, I have set the background-color to red just to make sure I can see that the div is actually a square.
As in the code, I do in fact see a red square in both SAFARI and FIREFOX.

The problem can be seen after I click the button which runs through the d3 code that appends the SVG element to the above div and add other SVG elements.

On SAFARI, everything works as I have expected.  The SVG element and the other SVG childs of the parent SVG element can be seen.

ON FIREFOX, nothing appears.

I then use FIREBUG to inspect the div and to see if d3 has in fact added the SVGs.  After inspecting, it is confirmed that ALL of the SVGs have been appended to the DOM and they are effectively the same as what was on SAFARI.
The difference is that on FIREFOX, nothing appears.
I then looked at the SVG element's attribute on FIREFOX. The width and height are both 100% as I've set.
I then play around with this, and instead of setting a percentage, I directly change the height and width to let's say 100 and the SVG finally appears.

In short, the same code works in SAFARI but does not in FIREFOX....

What's going on in FIREFOX that is preventing it from appearing?
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A JsFiddle would be helpful in this case.

Generally when you do responsive visualizations you'll need more control not only on the size of the viewport, but also on the elements being displayed. For example on smaller screen you'll have to decrease the number of ticks on the axis.

To do this, you can listen for resize events and adjust the graphics accordingly:

```
function resize() {
   /* Find the new window dimensions */
   var width = parseInt(d3.select("#graph").style("width")) - margin*2,
   height = parseInt(d3.select("#graph").style("height")) - margin*2;
}

d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);
```

Here is more information: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/02/17/building-responsible-visualizations-d3-js/